# Twitter keeps showing a notification about the same Direct Message

Tags: twitter, motorola-droid-razr

I've deleted the message from twitter on my computer, and from my phone both using the native twitter app, TweetDeck and the builtin social app. Yet every morning I've got a notice in my status bar and it's the same DM. I've received other DMs since then. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Which app did you originally use to send the DM? Try clearing data for that app.

Comment: It's a DM I received!

Comment: Do you know which app is showing the notification?

Comment: I'll add here that I had a similar problem, where Tweetdeck (TD) kept notifying me of a particular DM every time I opened it (like every few days on restarts for whatever reason). It was quite annoying. I searched and found this discussion, though no solution.

And then I found the solution (in TD, at least): it turns out that in TD's column holding my messages, I had not specifically clicked on the message to "read" it (which I guess marks it "read").  Clicking on the "notification" pop that TD was showing didn't do it.

I realize the OP may have solved this long ago. Hope it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in one of the apps you use. Best you can do is report it to their developers through the Play store.